# asp.net <%$ … %> syntax with conditional operator

Tags: asp.net, tags

```
<asp:Button ID="SubscribeButton" runat="server" CssClass="PopupButton" Text='<%# Eval("Payment_Method_Tkn").ToString() != "" ? "Unsubscribe"  : "Subscribe" %>'/>
```

works perfectly.

```
<asp:Button ID="SubscribeButton" runat="server" CssClass="PopupButton" Text="<%$ Resources:P2CWebStrings, UnsubscribeButtonLabel %>"/>
```

also works perfectly, correctly getting the value from the Resource file

However:

```
<asp:Button ID="SubscribeButton" runat="server" CssClass="PopupButton" Text='<%# Eval("Payment_Method_Tkn").ToString() != "" ? "<%$ Resources:P2CWebStrings, UnsubscribeButtonLabel %>" : "<%$ Resources:P2CWebStrings, SubscribeButtonLabel %>" %>' />
```

Displays "<%$ Resources:P2CWebStrings, UnsubscribeButtonLabel %>" on the screen instead of the Resource file value. Any idea how to fix it, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
<asp:Button ID="SubscribeButton" runat="server" CssClass="PopupButton" Text='<%# Eval("Payment_Method_Tkn").ToString() != "" ?  GetGlobalResourceObject("P2CWebStrings", "SubscribeButtonLabel") : GetGlobalResourceObject("P2CWebStrings", "UnsubscribeButtonLabel") %>'/>
```